# Memory performance with scrollView

Tags: ios, ipad, memory

I am creating a scrollview with 200 button in iPad and adding a image view on each button.
each image is of size 1 mb. but when i push scrollview screen app get crash.

So my question is.

What you people guess what is the reason?

what is the other best way to do this?

Comment: You should be using a `UITableView`.

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the accident is clear enough - 200Mb in memory for iOS is very-very much. A typical app uses about 10Mb in memory, and system can provide about 40Mb per 1 one app (I don't know is it true for ios5?). You should optimize your code. Look at [UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/) (instead of UIScrollView), this class uses reusable cells, so you can load only those images that are needed at the current time. I recommend also to try to compress your images.

Comment: I know but can paging facility of scrollview help this. as load page which i want.But i think also will be problem .at a time 2 3 page is loaded that's ok but when all page get load app will crash right?

Comment: UIScrollView always hold all content into the memory. Here you can find a lot of reusable components for iphone http://stackoverflow.com/questions/640805/open-source-ios-components-reusable-views-controllers-buttons-table-cells-e